# R, join two columns in a data frame nested within a list

Tags: r, list, dataframe, concatenation

1. There is a list (named d) of structurally identical data frames
2. Trying to create a new column in each of the data frames that joins two columns
3. I keep getting an invalid 'digits' argument with the following line
4. print(d[[1]]$Na.me1, d[[1]]$Na.me2)
5. The data in d[[1]]$Na.me1 and d[[1]]$Na.me2 are both integers

   ```
   [[1]]
   Na.me1        Na.me2         Na.me3
   10004563        382930        06042018
   10005637        326289        04052018
   ```
6. I am aiming for a 4th column that looks like "10004563 382930"

Comment: It is not clear from the description.  What is your expected output?  How is `Na.me3` created|?  May be `lapply(d, transform, newcol = Na.me1 - Na.me2)`

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please read [ask] and give a [mcve] (incl. the desired output)!

Comment: Please, be more specific with your question. It is hard to tell what exactly you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Try `print(c(d[[1]]$Na.me1, d[[1]]$Na.me2))`

Comment: Thanks everyone ... the only thing that worked for me was 
print(paste(d[[count]]$Na.me1,d[[count]]$Na.me2)) where I was using [[count]] in lieu of the [1] as I was looping through the list elements. If I replaced paste with c (per Ronak Shah) I got a vector that was 2x longer than original.

Answer (score 0):

We can use `lapply` to loop through the `list` and then create the column based on the description

```
lapply(d, transform, newcol = paste(Na.me1, Na.me2))
```

---

Or with `tidyverse`

```
library(tidyverse)
map(d, ~ .x %>%
            unite(newcol, Na.me1, Na.me2, sep=" ", remove = FALSE))
```